# How do I add something to the "Edit Tag" page in wp-admin?

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, tags, actions

I have some term_meta that I would like to display on the "Edit Tag" page in wp-admin. I found the following two action hooks, but both don't do what I want.

`edit_tag_form`

`edit_tag_form_pre`

These hooks either add something inside the form at the start, or at the end of the form, but before the "Update" and "Delete" buttons. What I would like to do is add entirely new section below the "Edit Tag" form that shows my term_meta.

Are there any hooks available for this?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

There is the `in_admin_footer` hook that's right before the "Thank you for creating with WordPress." text in the footer, you can check if you're on a tag edit screen in that hook.

```
function wpse_277416_admin_footer() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( $screen->id  === 'edit-post_tag' ) {
        echo 'Hello world!';
    }
}
add_action( 'in_admin_footer', 'wpse_277416_admin_footer' );
```

That's not quite what you want though, but there's no hooks between the submit button and the footer text.